# What do we have as UIButton(Sender: UIButton) in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui-form

in the UIKit I catch the button sender (which button is clicked) via code

```
       let colorVC = UIColorPickerViewController()
       colorVC.delegate = self
       clickedButton = sender
       present(colorVC, animated: true)
   }
```

I want to accomplish the same in SwiftUI.

Where flagList.name comes from struct and I would like to catch which button was clicked so I can adjust the Flag name accordingly.

````
``` Button(action: {
            
            print("tapped")
        }, label: {
            List(flagList) { flagList in
             
                
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                Image(flagList.flagName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .trailing)
                    
               
                    
                Text(flagList.name)
                    
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .light, design: .default))

                }
            }
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think your button is in the wrong place. You probably want a list of buttons, not a button that consists of a list.

Then, you can store a property that represents the currently selected button:

```
@State var currentSelectedFlagName: String
```

Note that I say *represents*, not *stores*. In SwiftUI, you shouldn't store references to individual views (including buttons).

You can then set `currentSelectedFlagName` to the current selected flag name when it's tapped.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    ...
    
    /// represents current selected button
    @State var currentSelectedFlagName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        List(flagList) { flagList in
            Button(action: {

                /// set the property
                currentSelectedFlagName = flagList.flagName
                print("tapped")
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    Image(flagList.flagName)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .trailing)
                    
                    Text(flagList.name)
                        .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .light, design: .default))
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```